# Git cherry-pick vs stash, switch and pop

Tags: git, version-control, merge

So I just ran into a problem when making some changes on one branch and realised I'd made an unrelated change to that branch.

The unrelated changes were pretty small (just one or two lines). So I committed the relevant changes and then attempted to switch to master (where I wanted to put the unrelated changes). The branch switch failed as there would be merge conflicts so I moved to the method I normally use for getting round this and stashed by changes and then moved to master. I applied the stash and hit a merge conflict! This surprised me as the changes were so simple.

Looking at the merge conflict in a merge tool I saw all sorts of code from my original feature branch - git had auto unselected these for me so there was no real danger of dragging them onto my master branch but it led me to think a little deeper about how stashes (and diffs) work - I didn't think a simple diff contained so much about where it had come from!

Anyway, after consulting a colleague I decided to attempt to move the changes onto master using git cherry pick instead - apparently that works differently. SO I made a temporary commit of the changes on the feature branch and then attempted to cherry pick those across onto master. I had exactly the same merge conflict!

So I fixed stuff up anyway and finished off the commit. But I wonder what is the recommended way of solving the problem I had (committing some changes on a different branch)? It's not really what git stash is intended for right? But making a commit on my feature branch (and then having to delete it) seems a little heavy handed.

Bonus points for ELI5 the differences (if any) between stash pop and cherry pick.

Comment: It's better to provide git commands output, including `git status`, `git log -n 2`, `git checkout` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking three questions:

1. What happened in this instance.
2. What to do in general.
3. What's the difference between checkout, stash/checkout/pop and commit/checkout/cherrypick.

In reverse order:

Question 3:

For this purpose, a checkout with unstaged changes in the tree is essentially the same as stash, checkout, stash pop. In both cases you're essentially taking a diff beforehand (of your unstaged changes), checking out some other branch, and then applying that diff (as a patch) onto the new branch, giving you the same unstaged changes, but with a different working tree.

(Stashing has some other features, such as allowing multiple stashes, but they aren't relevant here.)

This works fine if the diff (i.e. the unstaged changes) applies cleanly on top of the new working tree. If not, then the checkout approach will fail, while the stash pop will give you a merge conflict. Since the changes are probably trivial (or you'd otherwise be doing something more formal, such as making some commits), I tend to sort this sort of thing out manually: git diff on the old branch, then throw those changes away, checkout the new branch and apply the diff by hand, with due consideration of why it didn't apply cleanly in the first place. The stash approach just lets you use git's merge machinery to help you.

In none of this have we created a commit. Since a commit is essentially a diff, we could have created a commit for our desired changes on the original branch. We could then checkout the desired target branch and used cherry-pick: that copies commits (i.e. diffs) from one place to another. However, the diff's still the same diff as with the checkout and stash/checkout/pop methods, and so you'll still have merging problems if the diff doesn't apply cleanly. You don't magic those away by committing.

So:

- checkout: least structured. Dirty working tree. Essentially git diff > foo ; git checkout new-branch; patch -p1 < foo. No format record anywhere of the changes or where they came from.
- stash: more structured approach, since it records the dirtiness of the working tree as a temporary commit, perhaps with a message. You can apply it later on, perhaps having made some other changes and can easily use git's merge machinery to resolve conflicts.
- cherry-pick: most structured: like stash except the changes are a fully-fledged commit, rather than a temporary commit that's discarded when the stashed changes are applied.

A couple of notes about cherry-picking:

- There's no git relationship between the original commit (that's being cherry-picked) and the resulting commit (from cherry-picking a commit onto some other branch).
- If you use cherry-pick -x then git will include the original commit ref in the comment of the resulting commit, which at least gives you an element of traceability.

Question 2:

My opinion:

- No real difference between checkout and stash/pop. Personal preference, unless you want to lean on git merging.
- Depends on the amount of change involved and whether you need to be able to trace the change from its original location (on the feature branch) to its ultimate location (on master). If it's simple then checkout or stash/pop. If it's more involved, and/or committing on the original branch is sensible then commit there and get onto master (or a stable release branch) with whatever your organisation does (usually merge or cherry-pick).
- If you've accidentally committed an unrelated change on a feature branch **and you haven't pushed the feature branch** then you can sort things out by cherry-picking the change onto a more relevant branch and then discarding that commit from your feature branch. That keeps the git commit tree logically sensible at the cost of rewriting history. (Whether or not you should rewrite history tends to be a religious and/or organisational question.)

Question 1:

Your problem stems from the fact that your unrelated change depended on some of the changes on your feature branch that weren't yet on master. This means that the change (represented as an ordinary diff) wouldn't apply cleanly onto master, and so any automated means of applying that diff (whether checkout-with-dirty-working-tree, stash/pop or commit/cherry-pick) will fail with a merge conflict.

Comment: Great answer thank-you. This confirms my original gut feeling which was that as an operation a git stash-pop is the same as a cherry pick and then commit delete (some people had told me otherwise). I understand they are different in terms of how temporary the commits are (as your answer mentions) but your end state is the same in both.

Comment: One important technical note: a commit does *not* contain diffs, it contains an entire, intact tree of files.  The diff is computed dynamically every time someone asks for it.  The observable effect is the same in these cases, but if you go dig into the innards of a commit, it starts to matter; it also shows through somewhat in, e.g., the way `git show` shows diffs, which depends on things like one's `diff.renamelimit` setting (in git config files).  (And to be super-technical, git does store deltas in its "pack files", but they're not necessarily between ordinary files.)

Comment: @torek could you please about why git calculates diff when creating commit? (or why rebase/cherry-pick try to apply diff instead of copying full "state" represented by commit?)

Comment: @MrCricket: Git *doesn't* calculate a diff when making a snapshot (a commit). It just makes the snapshot (from whatever is in Git's *index* aka *staging area* at the time you run `git commit`). But consider what happens when you have two snapshots. Take a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) for instance. What is the difference between the left and right side snapshots in each pair of snapshots? How did you find out?

Comment: @torek I understand the need of a diff when _comparing_ snapshots. I don't understand why (for example) `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase` not just add new commit(=state) _as-is_ but try to compare and apply the diff (which can and up with conflicts)

Comment: @MrCricket: OK, suppose that in commit c123456, which I wish to cherry-pick, file F reads, in its entirety: "jumps over the lazy dog." This is what remains after I deleted the line "The quick brown fox", which was line 1 of file F in c123456's parent. I am now on commit a789abc, where file F has 500 lines, the first two being "The quick brown fox" and "jumps over the lazy dog". When I cherry pick commit c123456, do I want file F to read, in its entirety, just "jumps over the lazy dog", just one line long?

Comment: Note that this is a *legitimate question* because sometimes you really *do* want this. But more often, the answer to that is "no, I don't want that, I just want the first line deleted". (Note, too, that if you really do want to extract file F from commit c123456, you can do that. It's just that `git cherry-pick` is not the command that does it.)